# Is it okay to prospect my customer's customers?

Tags: communication, clients

Here is the situation: I have been working full-time for a customer (let's call him A) over the last month and most of this time was actually spent on projects from a single customer of them (let's call him B).

Now that I'm planning to launch a company that will be in direct competition with A, I'm wondering if I could tell B about it, give business cards and so on. 
How would that be perceived?

Answer (score 3):

You can, but it is generally **very** frowned upon.

Without express written disapproval, there's nothing *legally* preventing you doing so. Of course, a non-compete agreement would indicate there may be repercussions were you to do anything to compete with the employer, including stealing the clients.

*Stealing* customers from your employer will also **ensure** that employer does *everything* they can to prevent you from working once they find out. Client "sniping" is really one clear way to gain *horrible* word of mouth advertising.

Answer (score -1):

To hell with ethics, if you can do a better job than your "customer" and there is no paperwork such as an NDA or non-compete, then you would be doing the client a favor.